# Writing Unit Test with asynchronous code in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need to test my Api calls response but before the block return Unit test got completed
how can i test my APIs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `XCTestExpectation` for that.

```
XCTestExpectation *apiCallExpectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"APICall"];

[apiService apiCall:^(BOOL success) {
    XCTAssert(success);
    [apiCallExpectation fulfill];
}];

[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5 handler:^(NSError *error) {
    [apiCallExpectation closeWithCompletionHandler:nil];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, you don't need to call the actual API in unit testing, It shall to be independent and quicker to be completed. This shall be part of integration testing.

Regarding your question, I think you need to use Expectations, and Waiter. Check the following:

```
func testExample() {

  let responseExpectation = expectation(description: "response")

  // Your API Call shall be here
  DispatchQueue.main.async {

  // When you get the response, and want to finalize the expectation
  responseExpectation.fulfill()

  }

let result = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [responseExpectation], timeout: 15) // ex: 15 seconds to wait for the response for all expectations.

// result possible values are:

//all expectations were fulfilled before timeout.
.completed

//timed out before all of its expectations were fulfilled
.timedOut

//expectations were not fulfilled in the required order
.incorrectOrder

//an inverted expectation was fulfilled
.invertedFulfillment

//waiter was interrupted before completed or timedOut    
.interrupted

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is an example i am performing test case on a search api. you need to declare expectation and it will get fulfil once it's done.

```
func test_UpdateShowSearch_Result() {
        let promise = expectation(description: "Status code: 200")

        let searchAPI: SearchShowApi = SearchShowApi()

        searchAPI.search(query: "") { (statusCode, tvShows ,error) in
            if statusCode == 200 {

                // reload table
                promise.fulfill()

            } else if (statusCode == 204){
                // show no content
                XCTFail("Status code: \(statusCode)")
            }
            else{
                XCTFail("Error: \(String(describing:error?.localizedDescription))")
                return
            }

        }
        wait(for: [promise], timeout: 10)
    }
```